# Unit Testing using pytest

Tags: python

Define a pytest test method 'test_add_new_stock_as_dict', which adds the new stock {'iPhone Model X':50, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 2000, 'Nokia Model A':10} to the existing
inventory, and update the balance_inventory attribute. Also, check if the updated balance_inventory equals {'iPhone Model X':150, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 3000,
'Nokia Model Z':25, 'Nokia Model A':10}.

I wrote this code:

```
def test_add_new_stock_as_dict(self):
    self.inventory({'iPhone Model X': 50, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 2000, 'Nokia Model A': 10})
    assert self.inventory.balance_inventory == {'iPhone Model X': 150, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 3000, 'Nokia Model Z': 25, 'Nokia Model A': 10}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'MobileInventory' object is not callable
```

Where is my mistake, please suggest.

Comment: Could you post MobileInventory, and also your pytest class? But first try assert self.inventory... at the second line, instead of assert MobileInventory.

Comment: Each test is supposed to be independent.  You should not rely on other tests.

Comment: def test_add_new_stock_as_dict(self):
        self.inventory = MobileInventory({'iPhone Model X': 50, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 2000, 'Nokia Model A': 10})
        assert self.inventory.balance_inventory == {'iPhone Model X': 150, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 3000, 'Nokia Model Z': 25, 'Nokia Model A': 10}                                                            I did it, still I am getting error

Comment: You need to post the error message. We cannot guess.

Comment: are you getting the same error after changing the test? is it possible to show the class MobileInventory?

Comment: It is not possible to show the class MobileInventory

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance 'Inventory' as

```
def setup_class():
    inventory=MobileInventory({'iPhone Model X':100, 'Xiaomi Model Y': 1000, 'Nokia 
              Model Z':25})
```